# How to make directory path relative so that we can run code in both Mac and windows

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, filepath

I am using Python to open web-driver. The driver path is absolute.
How can I make this absolute path dynamic so that I can run the same code on Windows as well?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driverpath="/Users/abhinavwadhankar/PycharmProjects/PythonAutomationFramework/Drivers/chromedriver-5"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverpath)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
print(driver.title)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what have you tried? The drive path is not a windows path, and cannot work on windows.

Comment: improved the grammar; added a code block; added "selenium" and "selenium-webdriver" tags

Comment: What solution other than "don't put an absolute path" do you hope for?

Comment: use https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.system and see where the code is running. change `driverpath` accordingly